# Error occurred while adding a new consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, celery-task, kombu

I am getting following error when I am trying to add a new consumer(queue) from the `current_app` imported from celery by issuing the control command.

The details of logged error are as follows:

```
reply = current_app.control.add_consumer(queue_name, destination = WORKER_PROCESSES, reply = True)
File "/opt/msx/python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 232, in add_consumer
**kwargs
File "/opt/msx/python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 307, in broadcast
limit, callback, channel=channel,
File "/opt/msx/python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 300, in _broadcast
channel=chan)
File "/opt/msx/python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 336, in _collect
with consumer:
    File "/opt/msx/python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 396, in __enter__
self.consume()
File "/opt/msx/python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 445, in consume
self._basic_consume(T, no_ack=no_ack, nowait=False)
File "/opt/msx/python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 567, in _basic_consume
no_ack=no_ack, nowait=nowait)
File "/opt/msx/python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 611, in consume
nowait=nowait)
File "/opt/msx/python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/librabbitmq/__init__.py", line 81, in basic_consume
no_local, no_ack, exclusive, arguments or {},

ChannelError: basic.consume: server channel error 404, message: NOT_FOUND - no queue '2795c73e-2b6a-34d6-bd1f-13de0d1e5497.reply.celery.pidbox' in vhost '/'
```

I didn't understand the error. I am passing a queue name different from the one mentioned in logs.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Note: This issue starts occurring after setting MAX_TASK_PER_CHILD value. Is this related to the error ?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3220

Comment: seems so. It is possible that 2 different servers are trying to add the same queue and trying to fetch the return value message at the same time, as retry parameter is set to True.

But, how shall I handle this error. Is a try/except is a proper work around ?
I require to find whether the queue is added or not. My retry logic is based on that.